# How can I create a list containing another list's elements in the middle in python?

Tags: python, list

I have three lists. Two are returned from functions. The other list, `list_c`, is being created in the program out of some hardcoded options and some variables, and the contents of these lists. This list is a list of arguments to be passed to another program, so the order is important. I need each item in `list_a` and `list_b` to be in the middle of `list_c` in a certain position. Both `list_a` and `list_b` are variable in length.

```
list_a = some_function()
list_b = some_other_function()
list_c = ['some', 'stuff', list_a, 'more', list_b, variables]
```

Basically, I want something like the above, except giving a flat list instead of a nested list.

I could do:

```
list_c = ['some', 'stuff']
list_c.extend(list_a)
list_c.append('more')
list_c.extend(list_b)
list_c.append(variables)
```

but that looks a bit clunky and I was curious if there was a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this? You can append/concatenate lists with `+`

`['some', 'stuff'] + some_function() + ['more'] + some_other_function() + [variables]`

Comment: Although this will create quite a few unneeded copies.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious way to do this is to use list concatenation:

```
list_c = list_c + list_a + ['more'] + list_b + ['var1', 'var2']
```

For what it's worth, `itertools.chain` also works. I don't know why the answer suggesting it was deleted. If the author undeletes it, I'll remove this from my answer.

```
>>> list_a = ['some_function', 'results']
>>> list_b = ['some_other_function', 'results']
>>> variables = 'foo'
>>> list_c = list(itertools.chain(['some', 'stuff'], list_a, ['more'], list_b, [variables]))
>>> list_c
['some', 'stuff', 'some_function', 'results', 'more', 'some_other_function', 'results', 'foo']
```

Yet another solution:

```
>>> lists_to_chain = [['some', 'stuff'], list_a, ['more'], list_b, [variables]]
>>> list_c = []
>>> for l in lists_to_chain:
...     list_c.extend(l)
... 
>>> list_c
['some', 'stuff', 'some_function', 'results', 'more', 'some_other_function', 'results', 'foo']
```

Comment: I want the flat list. The example that gives a nested list was where I wanted something "like the above" (the first example) that gave the results from the second example. I'll make that clearer now.

Comment: @Not Joe Bloggs, oh, I see -- I actually slightly misread your post. Still, it's clearer now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y,
       [['some', 'stuff'], some_function(), ['more'], some_other_function(), variables])
```

is more flexible than hardcoding `['some', 'stuff'] + some_function() + ['more'] + some_other_function() + [variables]` because you can define and manipulate the containing list  at runtime before you merge it.